# storing client connection on bidirectional call

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have simple bidirectional rpc proto interface, such as:

```
rpc RouteData(stream RouteNote) returns (stream ProcessedRouteNote) {}
```

The thing is that it might takes a while until I can return `ProcessedRouteNote`.

I would like to know what is the recommended way to store away a connected client so I could stream back a response(i.e. "ProcessedRouteNote") at a later time?

```
"def RouteData(self, request_iterator, servicer_context)"
```

It seems that saving "**request_iterator**" of "def RouteData", which is "**RpcMethodHandler**",  and then calling directly to stream_stream would do the job.

Will appreciate any feedback.

***I could probably simplify this question further by asking:*** How can I send data/response to a specific client that has previously sent a request(bidirectional) to the server? It should be noted that the intention is to send the response not in the context of the server's RPC handler. Moreover, there could be dozen of requests but only single response. So I have no interest to block RPC handler to wait for response. I really hope this is possible with grpc, otherwise it is really a deal breaker for us.

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generator yielding response values and waiting for a `threading.Event` object to trigger that might be stored in a hashtable somewhere depending on your application logic.

Comment: That's not the answer that I'm looking for. I'd like to have the ability to send reply from different context all together - different thread, different function. I don't want to block the RPC thread by waiting on event(and I would still like to get more requests while preparing the response) .

Comment: @Mike the current gRPC Python service handler API is not asynchronous, so except when writing, a thread is consumed by each request, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, this question has nothing to do with request-replay pairs, so there is no need for the request handler to be asynchronous. The question has to do with sending data which doesn't have to be tied to a certain request. Again, I'm looking for a way to send data to a certain client, not in the context of the service handler, possibly by saving the request iterator(that is accessible and is being passed in RPC request handler) or some other client context